# сделать TimeOut на запрос FireBase

Tags: java, android, firebase-database

Собственно надо обработать ошибку соединения. Пропала сеть итд. При запросе к базе `FireBase` , когда вызывается `addChildEventListener` думаю сделать таймаут на запрос, к примеру 10 секунд. Что бы в некоторых случаях показывать сообщение об Ошибке. 
Сам `addChildEventListener` такого метода не предоставляет. Может кто то делал подобное ?

Сеть проверяю вот так:

```
if (!NetworkChecker.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
        showToast(getString(R.string.connection_error));
    }
```

Ну и сам запрос:

```
        private void GetDataFireBase(String columnFireBaseData) {

                DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child(columnFireBaseData);
                databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                ItemCatalog item = dataSnapshot.getValue(ItemCatalog.class);
                autoList.add(item);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onChildChanged: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onChildRemoved: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onChildMoved: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: ");


        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase предоставляет механизм работы с базой даже при отсутствии [подключения](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline). 
То есть ваши данные будут доступны, даже если пропадет подключение.

И еще, у вас есть метод проверки доступности сети, сделайте для него **runnable** и установите таймер, после чего показывайте свой тост.